# Non-idempotent Python

Tags: popularity-contest, python, programming-puzzle

Write a few lines of Python code, `X`, that does not reference any global variables, such that

```
def method():
    X
    print(a)

method()
```

prints `1` but

```
def method():
    X
    X
    print(a)

method()
```

prints `2`.

---

So, I hate to be a stickler, but it seems like `vars` and `locals` are actually global variables in Python:

```
def test_global_1():
    global vars, locals
    vars = lambda: 2
    locals = lambda: 3

def test_global_2():
    print(vars())
    print(locals())

test_global_1()
test_global_2()
```

---

Also, it looks like people would like to see objective winning criteria for puzzles like this. Code length doesn't really feel right here so perhaps we could make a system of brownie points for various novel features of the code? I'm not sure exactly what these could be but here's a start:

- +1 for really truly no globals (no `vars` or `locals`)
- +1 for being the first to post a particular technique
- +1 for the shortest solution posted
- +1 for a solution involving only a single Python statement
- +1 for interesting "hacks" like joining at lexical non-boundaries
- +1 for not using exceptions

And if you can think of more you could edit this question to add to the list.

Can this problem be solved without using exceptions *and* without using globals like `vars` and `locals`? I suspect it can, though I haven't figured out exactly how yet...

Comment: Good puzzle! I made sure not to scroll down so I could solve it myself without seeing anyone's answers. :D

Comment: Thanks for the puzzles Owen, and welcome to the site. There is a rule on the site that all questions must have an objective winning condition, so you should probably add one. One possibility is shortest length of `X`, but there are other options.

Comment: "all questions must have an objective winning condition" - Stupid rule imho. Who cares about a "winner" when we all actually most enjoy the puzzling and learning from the different answers.

Comment: Please add a [tag:code-golf] or [tag:popularity-contest] tag, depending on whether you want people to optimize for shortness code or for general popularity. I imagine code-golf is better for this challenge (popularity-contest is encouraged only for challenges that cannot be easily classified otherwise), but it's up to you.

Comment: [Ongoing meta discussion.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5585/20260)

Comment: You've added a scoring system, but also added the popularity contest tag, which means that a winner is decided by votes. What do you mean here? Perhaps you want votes just as a tiebreak?

Comment: You've added something saying 'vars' and 'locals' are in fact global variables, but I think your reasoning is flawed.  Prior to your defining 'vars' and 'locals', they *weren't* global variables; this can be verified by looking at globals().

Comment: The restrictions you're adding are starting to make me think an answer is provably impossible.  And I think your wording "a few lines of code" implies complete lines, which rules out clever hacks like joining at non-lexical boundaries.   So, could I win by providing a compelling impossibility proof?

Comment: @DonHatch An impossibility proof would count, yes.

Comment: Unfortunately question is on hold but I want to sneak in my answer anyway :P My code `X` would be `a=method.a=method.__dict__.get('a',0)+1`.

Comment: No fun allowed guys

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```python
def method():
    if 'a' not in vars():a=0
    a+=1
    if 'a' not in vars():a=0
    a+=1
    print(a)
```

Initializes the variable `a` to `0` only if it's not already initialized in the variables table. Then, increments it.

More briefly (thanks to histocrat for `len`):

```python
def method():
    a=len(vars())+1
    a=len(vars())+1
    print(a)
```

If the two copies of `X` could be on the same line, we could do

```python
a=0;a+=1;a
```

which doubles to

```python
a=0;a+=1;aa=0;a+=1;a
```

with the "sacrificial lamb" `aa` eating up the second variable assignment.

Comment: I don't want to be a spoilsport posting this so fast, so how about we try for shortest code?

Comment: Slightly shorter variant: `a=len(vars())+1`

Comment: @histocrat Nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## Python

Thought of this solution, since `try` and `except` was the first way I thought of to determine if a variable existed yet or not.

```python
def method():
    try:a+=1
    except:a=1
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2

```python
def method():
    exec'';locals()['a']=locals().get('a',0)+1
    exec'';locals()['a']=locals().get('a',0)+1
    print a

method()
```

Basically, when `exec` is encountered in Python 2, it causes a special flag (`0x01`) to be removed from `method.func_code.co_flags`, which makes `locals` assignments have an effect. I exploited this to implement [`nonlocal` support in Python 2](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578965-python-2-nonlocal/) (see line 43 for the xor that modifies the flag).

Comment: Why not `a = locals().get('a', 0) + 1`?

Comment: @Vincent I was tiree. :O Fixed.

Comment: In that case you don't need `exec''` any more ;)

Comment: @Vincent Eh, maybe I should just stick with the longer version. It felt more creative. Now it just seems a lot like a clone of the top-voted answer... :/

Answer (score 2):

My first idea (and then smooshing it) was:

```
def method():
    a=2if'a'in vars()else 1 
    a=2if'a'in vars()else 1 
    print(a)
```

But histocrat's answer seems optimal.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt. Uses the math module to track if X is run once or twice.

```
def module():
  import sys
  if 'math' in sys.modules:
    a+=1
  else:
    a=1
  import math

  import sys
  if 'math' in sys.modules:
    a+=1
  else:
    a=1
  import math

  print(a)

module()
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
def method():
    #### X-block
    try:a
    except NameError:a=1
    else:a=2
    ####
    print(a)
```

The `try` block checks if the variable a is defined.
If variable not defined,(this is only when X-block is present once) then `NameError` Exception is raised.
If variable is defined, (this is when X-block is present twice) then `else` will be entered .

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution I found by searching Google. Then I created my current solution, which is shorter.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yeah :P. Your way is shorter than using `else`

Answer (score 0):

```
def method(a=[]):  
  a.append(a)  
  print len(a)
```

Edited in response to comment:  a is a list of empty lists of length n, where n is the number of time you've called method.  Calling this method twice prints 1 then 2.

Comment: Putting `a=[]` as a parameter is outside the parameters for this challenge.

Comment: Sorry, this is my answer, and it's not very good.  This is (arguably) a surprisingly non-idempotent operation in python, but there's no way to slot it into the format provided for the challenge without also making the challenge trivial.

Comment: Also, the challenge asks to print 1 or 2, not just two different things.